# Why is fglrx's package version higher than fglrx-updates?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, package-management, fglrx

I'm having problems with the DRI infrastructure and the fglrx drivers. When searching for a solution I have noticed that in Synaptic the `fglrx` package is at  version **9.002** and `fglrx-updates` is at **8.960**, what is the Canonical policy on this?

What is the point of having an *updated* version much older than the *standard* version ?

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 amd64.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with Canonical, but with availability from other sources. Did you by any chance try to install fglrx from the ati website or from a PPA?

With `apt-cache policy <packagename>` you can check which version is installed on your system and which version is in the repositories.

Output for `fglrx`:

```
fglrx:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:8.960-0ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
     2:9.002-0ubuntu1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:8.960-0ubuntu1.1 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
     2:8.960-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/restricted amd64 Packages
```

Output for `fglrx-updates`

```
fglrx-updates:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:8.960-0ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
     2:8.960-0ubuntu1.1 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
     2:8.960-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/restricted amd64 Packages
```

As you can see in the ubuntu repositories both are version 8.960, the 9.002 is only in my list because I installed it in the past from the ati website.

EDIT: You can check which version you have installed by

```
 dpkg -l | grep fglrx | grep ii
```

or if you installed without using the package manager

```
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep fglrx | grep -A4 'Kernel Module Version Information'
```

Comment: when using synaptics there is a special icon for the packages that come from a PPA, this isn't the case, however i can't be sure if i have installed debs manually after generating packages from the official AMD ATI package for linux. I have checked online and they are both at 8.960 apparently http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/fglrx-updates which makes even less sense to me.

Comment: This confirms my answer; the most logical conclusion is that you installed the deb packages you generated from the AMD website, since there is no way you installed them from the repositories, and synaptic (and most likely `apt-cache policy fglrx`) shows it is not from a PPA.